# Get Unique Device ID Ionic without the PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the unique device id without the ionic app asking to make or manage phone calls.
How do I get rid of the permission and keep using the UnigueDeviceID plugin?
Below is the code for getting the deviceid using the plugin
[the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxjxh.png)
 `var deviceid = (this.uniqueDeviceID.get().then((uuid: any)=> deviceid = uuid));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you cannot get the unique device ID without getting the phonestate permission